# Task.Factory.StartNew() doesn't include Exception when using ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I am trying to create a parallel process that wouldn't block my main thread but still log errors in case there is an exception. Originally I had this code:

```
var task = Task.Run(
    () => _db.addData());

task.ContinueWith(continuationTask =>
    {
        if (continuationTask.Exception != null)
        {
            _logger.LogError(continuationTask.Exception, "Failed to log mismatch");
        }
    },
    _taskScheduler);
```

When running the application code `_taskScheduler` is set to `TaskScheduler.Current`.
When running this, it correctly executes the code in parallel and when there is a problem with the database, `continuationTask.Exception` contains the appropriate exception message.

The whole point of specifying the `TaskScheduler` was so I can control the order of execution in a unit test. As it stands at the moment, in a unit test, the original task and the continuation would run using different task schedulers - `TaskScheduler` and `MockTaskScheduler` respectively. (not showing the unit test code for brevity but `MockTaskScheduler` is just a custom implementation that allows me to queue and execute tasks)

As `Task.Run` doesn't take a `TaskScheduler` as a parameter I tried changing the code to

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => _db.addData(),
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    _taskScheduler);

task.ContinueWith(continuationTask =>
    {
        if (continuationTask .Exception != null)
        {
            _logger.LogError(continuationTask.Exception, "Failed to log mismatch");
        }
    },
    _taskScheduler);
```

This makes my test work perfectly as I can now control when each task gets executed because they use the same injectable `_taskScheduler`. However, when running the application code using `TaskScheduler.Current`, `continuationTask.Exception` is always null thus preventing me from logging any exception.

Is there a reason why `Task.Run` populates the `continuationTask.Exception` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't? Am I missing something?

Comment: The current scheduler is set up because of `ContinueWith` not `Task.Run`. Use `await Task.Run.`

Comment: I don't want to await the task, this will make my code synchronous.

Comment: Your code is already asynchronous, but just with using another syntax.

Comment: Depending on the return type of addData, it is likely that `task` in the second case is, `Task<Task>`. Task.Run automatically unwraps inner tasks like this, but if you are using StartNew you have to do it manually. Try `task.Unwrap().ContinueWith(...`.

Comment: Thanks @MikeZboray that did the trick. The return type of `addData` was a task indeed. As suggested, it seems the exception of the inner task was getting lost. Adding `task.Unwrap().ContinueWith()` fixed the problem. 
If you add this as an answer I'll set it as the approved one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mike Zboray mentioned in the comments, I needed to call `task.Unwrap().ContinueWith()` as I had nested tasks. This is only necessary when using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` as `Task.Run()` unwraps nested tasks automatically.

My final code looks like this:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => _db.addData(),
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    _taskScheduler);

task.Unwrap().ContinueWith(continuationTask =>
    {
        if (continuationTask .Exception != null)
        {
            _logger.LogError(continuationTask.Exception, "Failed to log mismatch");
        }
    },
    _taskScheduler);
```